# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges Não funciona em background

Tags: ios, swift, geolocalização, gps, swift-3

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que utiliza o serviço de localização do dispositivo. Ele necessariamente precisa estar capturando as posições quando há uma mudança de local e deve capturar em todas as situações (*background/foreground/killed*), então estou utilizando o método *startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()*, porém quando eu envio ele para background, a captura de posições roda apenas por mais algum tempo e para, depois disso não captura mais. Eu me locomovo a distância que a documentação sugere para atualização (500m) de posição e nada acontece. O que posso estar fazendo de errado? Obs: No simulador funciona perfeitamente, porém no dispositivo fisico não funciona.

O arquivo *Info.plist* está com a configuração de background habilitada

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>location</string>
  </array>
```

*AppDelegate.swift*

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if (launchOptions != nil) {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = ViewController()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.other
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    return true
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = ViewController()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.other
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}
```

*ViewController.swift*

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {    
    //Trato a captura da nova localização 
}
```

Comment: Qual é o dispositivo que você está usando? Modelo e versão do iOS

Comment: @FelipeRicieri testei em um iPhone 5 e um iPhone 6, ambos com a versão 10.3

Comment: locationManager.delegate = ViewController() não esta correto voce precisa fazer isso dentro do seu view controller e coloca `locationManager.delegate = self`.  ViewController() vai gerar uma instance que não é a mesma do view controller do seu app

Comment: @LeoDabus Esse código está dentro do _AppDelegate.swift_ para que eu possa usar os callbacks que estão na minha _ViewController.swift_. No simulador ele funciona perfeitamente, mas no dispositivo fisico não funciona

Comment: "para que eu possa usar os callbacks que estão na minha ViewController.swift" não faz sentido nenhum. Faz o que eu te disse se não entendeu edita a sua pergunta

Comment: Esse seu código no AppDelegate não tem como funcionar. Se tem algo funcionando não é isso. Além do problema da instancia do ViewController não ser a mesma, voce declarou locationManager como uma variável local dentro do método, quando esse método applicationDidEnterBackground acabar de ser executado ela vai simplesmente ser descartada pelo compiler. Ela simplesmente deixa de existir.

Answer (score -1):

Duas sugestões...

Notei que, no código enviado, você não tá solicitando a permissão para pegar a localização do usuário... Talvez isso seja um problema. Para resolver isso, basta colocar no viewDidLoad: locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

Outra possibilidade é que na documentação consta que essa função não manda notificações seguidas em menos de 5 minutos. Ou seja, ainda que você se desloque mais de 500 metros, se ainda não passaram 5 minutos da última notificação, o app não vai te notificar novamente até que passem esses 5 minutos.

Se você precisar verificar mais frequentemente que isso as mudanças de localização do usuário, acho que você vai ter que usar o startUpdatingLocation() e calcular se o usuário se mexeu o suficiente ou não...

Comment: Eu solicito a permissão para pegar a localização do usuário na hora que ele entra no aplicativo, na  _ViewController_. O teste que eu fiz foi caminhar durante 30 minutos, e durante o trajeto eu parei por 10 minutos. Será que já seria o suficiente? Então eu queria o seguinte comportamento, quando está com o aplicativo aberto eu quero que capture a localização mais frequentemente, então eu uso o `startUpdatingLocation` e quando o aplicativo vai para background eu quero utilizar o `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`, por isso o meu código está no _AppDelegate_ será que é possível?

Comment: Desculpa, só verificando... Você pediu a permissão só para quando o app estiver em uso ou pra sempre? Como você vai usar o app em background teria que ser "sempre".

Comment: Outra coisa... Você fez as configurações no projeto pra permitir a atualização no background? Eu nunca precisei fazer nada que rodasse em background, mas pesquisando achei o tutorial do link no fim desse comentário. E acho que o código não precisa estar no appDelegate, precisa?  https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Sim, eu solicito para o usuário a permissão "sempre". Também habilitei no _capabilities_ para que o app rode em background. No simulador ele funciona perfeitamente, com todos os comportamento que preciso. Porém quando vou testar com um dispositivo real, ele não funciona como esperado.